# Outlet is Live, but Main is OFF?

Tags: electrical

Ok, so I am trying to replace the light switches in my garage; I shut of the breaker, but the switches were still reading voltage using my non-contact sensor; I go back and switch off other breakers, assuming the breaker was mislabeled; still, it senses voltage. I shut off every breaker in the panel (except the Main), and it still reads voltage.  [scratching head further]

Heck, I shut off the Main.....that surely will do the trick!  Voltage continues. [puzzled and generally concerned].  Here is a short video clip of the circumstances: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6sfNdtoREigd2kyZU4yRWR0b3M

Any suggestions???

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? Can you check the voltage using it? And did you verify the NCVT works properly on a known-live circuit first?

Comment: Have you tried actually putting a load on the circuit (e.g. a lightbulb)?

Comment: I agree with @Daniel Griscom, non contact meters can pickup induced voltage. With a small load on the line the voltage drops to a point the non contact meter won't see it.

Comment: Especially in an old installation, there's a non-zero chance of miswiring so bad that the circuit is switched on the natural. Now that your suspicions have been raised it would be a good idea to measure voltage to a decent ground from all contacts before touching them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, a high-impedance meter can detect the very small amount of electricity coupled across the breaker by capacitance from outside power lines running parallel to the house... but as also mentioned, someone could have bypassed the breaker, so you need to check that there's less than ~20 mA available.

Put a small (1 or 2 watt) night-light across the circuit, with the breaker off... if it lights, call in an electrician to fix this dangerous condition. Note that *neon* lamps glow visibly with only a mA or two, so are over-sensitive for this application.